# Applying a mathematical function to a list of factors in python

Tags: python

I have a function that returns a list of the factors of a number "n":

```
def factors(n): 
    i = 2
    factlist = []
    while i <= n:
        if n% i == 0:
            factlist.append(i)
        i = i + 1
    return factlist
```

Now I'm trying to create a function that counts how many times a factor is a factor of n. I have a function called "howManyTimesDivides" that returns this:

```
def howManyTimesDivides(n, d):
    i = 0
    while n%d==0:
        n /= 2
        i += 1
    return i
```

Now, I'm trying to combine these two, but I cannot seem to apply the howManyTimesDivides function to a list "a = factors(n)". Here's what I have:

```
from collections import Counter
def factorCounts(n):
    a = factors(n)
    map(howManyTimesDivides(n,a), a)
    return dict(Counter(divides))
```

Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
def factorCounts(n):
    a = factors(n)
    b = [howManyTimesDivides(n, i) for i in a]
    return b

print(factorCounts(20))
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
```